# Hi! I updated my laptop but I shut down accidetally causing for the update to be incomplete. Now, my laptop doesn't work properly. What to do?

Tags: updates, keyboard, mouse

I can't use the mouse. There's a box where I can partially update the OS. But I can't click it because the mouse is not working. Help!

Comment: Have you finished updating

Answer (score 2):

Once you have turned-on your laptop, you press

```
    ctrl+alt+f1
```

keys, and then login and then run the update command.

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

### First line

This line is used to update your repositories list, your servers latest available packages details will be downloaded.

### second line:

Reads your package list and updates your system if any new packages were available.

### Third line

It upgrades if your disk has got any updates.

so, First you need to run 1st line and 2nd and the 3rd line.(Separately) 
After completing your update you 'restart' your laptop, by typing

```
    reboot
```

If you wish to switch to graphical desktop while you are in virtual terminal (ctrl+alt+f1), then press

```
    ctrl+alt+f7
```

That's it.

Comment: The OP may have been updating using the GUI, so it's probably worth listing what the update commands are.

Comment: I have updated  the answer